# How to resolve an Error after importing a package in Enterprse Architect Sparx Systems

Tags: sql, enterprise-architect

Everytime I want to change some properties in some class I get the following error messages:

:Microsoft Cursor Engine [-2147217864]
Row cannot be located for updating. Some values may have been changed since it was last read.

ADODB.Recordset[-2146825069]
Operation is not allowed in this context.

How can I solve them??

Answer (score 5):

Even if this question was posted a long time ago:

Now and then this error occurs in my projects, too.
Every time I try to edit specific elements in Enterprise Architect projects i get exactly the same error messages. The only solution to this is to delete the element completely and create it again.

@TomO:

> When you are importing a package, is this from XMI or are you import a source code directory?

I import only via XMI file.

> What are you using as a repository?

I'm using a PostgreSQL-Server based repository, which I access via ODBC Driver.

> In your ODBC Data Source Configuration do you have "Return matched rows instead of affected rows" and "Allow big result sets".

Could specify where I can find these options? Perhaps this is outdated, becaus I can't find any of these options under the Options/Datasource Menu in my ODBC driver.

> If you are importing form XMI are you stripping the GUIDs on import, this is always a good idea if you are making a copy of an existing folder in your model as having two elements with the same GUID is not ideal ;-)

I strip GUIDs when I'm exporting and again when I'm importing XMI files.

I would really apprechiate any help concerning this topic.

Comment: Go to Start -> ODBC Data Sources, then select the connection and click to Configure. If is a MySQL connection click on Details >>, and you'll find options in these tabs.

Answer (score 2):

If possible i might need a little more information. When you are importing a package, is this from XMI or are you import a source code directory? What are you using as a repository? Given the error I am assuming it is not the local EAP file.

In your ODBC Data Source Configuration do you have "Return matched rows instead of affected rows" and "Allow big result sets"

If you are importing form XMI are you stripping the GUIDs on import, this is always a good idea if you are making a copy of an existing folder in your model as having two elements with the same GUID is not ideal ;-)

I have also noticed that you asked this on Apr 14th - sorry it has taken me so long to find your request. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Are you accessing your ea repository as a cloud repository please? If so, you could try to switch to access the repository as an odbc datasource, and this problem might be solved. I think it is a bug of the Sparx enterprise architect cloud service.